# While using tkinter, why should I use "indirect" callbacks?

Tags: python, tkinter, callback

I am trying improve my Python and tkinter skills. At this moment I am reading a book on tkinter. I noticed that in an object oriented GUI application the author defines the button callbacks this way:

```
def on_fast_forward_button_clicked(self):
    self.player.fast_forward()

def on_rewind_button_clicked(self):
    self.player.rewind()
```

So, if I understand correctly, we are writing to methods for each button in the application class. One with the "indirect" callback, called but the event, and other with the intended action itself, called by the previous one. Why should we write code like this, instead of just using a single method?

Comment: FYI, indent by four spaces to format code properly. I've fixed it up this time.

Comment: @Carcigenicate right. I was not able to do it on mobile app, but I would edit it anyway later on computer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: In the app, there's a `{}` button above the keyboard that auto formats highlighted text. Just so you know. Not a big deal.

Comment: Yes, I know. I tapped that button, but for some weird reason, the spaces disapeared and would not appear back. Not sure if that is a bug or a feature.

Comment: If some of the lines are indented weird, it has odd behavior. But if you know about it, then ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no specific reason, and in the example you give I absolutely wouldn't do it that way.

It's really quite simple: in general terms, every button should be associated with a function. That's it. That's the rule. What that function does is totally up to you.

If all it ever does is a single thing, there's no reason it can't directly call that single thing. If it needs to do more than one thing, create a special purpose function that does everything the button should do, and have that button call that function.

That being said, there's a conceptual difference between "responding to a button" and "performing an action". For example, you might have two or three ways to do the fast-forward function: you might have a command on the menubar, a command on a right-click menu, a dedicated fast-forward button, and a keyboard accelerator.

Depending on how these are implemented, the functions they call may or may not require extra arguments (eg: a function bound to an event always gets an event object). In that case it is often easier to have a special purpose function that is designed to respond to the event, and that special purpose function call the more general-purpose `fast_forward` function.

At the end of the day, it's all about clarity. If you think it makes the program easier to understand when you have a single function perform two roles (fastforward, and respond to a button click), by all means do it that way.

Answer (score 2):

Think about it like this: currently, all the button does is have the player fast forward. What if in the future however you also wanted the clock, or some other entity to fast forward with it? Would it make any sense to stick those fast forward calls inside `player.fast_forward()`? Should the player's methods really have access to information like that?

`on_fast_forward_button_clicked` is acting as a wrapper to encompass everything that may need to be fast forwarded. If you ever need to add any functionality, all you need to do is make a minor modification:

```
def on_fast_forward_button_clicked(self):
    self.player.fast_forward()
    self.clock.fast_forward()
```

Comment: I see. It makes sense. I wonder if it could have any kind of effect in app responsivity, or it should behave in the same way. I mean, if the `self.player.fast_forward()` method takes a few seconds to complete, the GUI still freezes, right?

Comment: @Victor As a general rule, callbacks should return as soon as possible if they're being run on the main application thread. Yes, if each fast forward call is long running, it may cause an issue. That's just compounding an existing problem though, not creating a new one.

Comment: Ok. Everything seems logical. one of these days I will have to dig a little into threading and try to conciliate it with tkinter. I have a project that gets a "spining beachball" (on Mac) when the app waits for a web request to be completed. I must rewrite that part :)

Comment: I'd wonder why the fast forward code would be long running though. It may be a good idea to try to reduce that part down to a [Mcve] and post it on Code Review. They might be able to help you speed it up.

Comment: Well. I was thinking about other contexts, where the method called could be more complex. I will investigate further and place a new question it the need arises.